# Discord.py Give role to user - 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to write a bot which gives a user a role so they can see their ban information. Everything is working, apart from actually giving the user said role. I've found conflicting advice on these forums, reddit and the docs - but none of the solutions seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
role = await message.guild.create_role(name=ban_str)
category = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, name="Tickets")
overwrites = {
    message.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
}
channel = await message.guild.create_text_channel(banstr, category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
user = client.get_user(int(user_id))
await discord.Member.add_roles(user, role, reason="[Ban Ticket] Added user to ticket " + banstr)
```

And I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

I have tried to make the "user" a member object, replacing `user = client.get_user(int(user_id))` with `user = message.guild.get_member(int(user_id))`, but then I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'
```

If anyone can see anything I'm doing wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `message.guild.get_member()`

`User` has no set guild as user is just a person of what is your id? What is your avatar and so on. `Member` is what has a guild attached to it.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for responding, when I use `user = message.guild.get_member(int(user_id))` instead of `client.get_user()` I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'`. How would I make a member object from a user ID?

Comment: @Ethan did you enable the `members` intent?

Answer (score 0):

Try `user = await client.fetch_user(int(user_id))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
# Firstly you have to enable all intents in you bot application in the developer portal
# Secondly you should read what's there standing as description and maybe configure it for this

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
...

role = await message.guild.create_role(name=ban_str)
category = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, name="Tickets")
overwrites = {
    message.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
}
channel = await message.guild.create_text_channel(banstr, category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
user = client.get_user(int(user_id))
await user.add_roles(role, reason="[Ban Ticket] Added user to ticket " + banstr)
```

Else if you still get a `NoneType` from `.get_user()` try:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
# Firstly you have to enable all intents in you bot application in the developer portal
# Secondly you should read what's there standing as description and maybe configure it for this

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
...

role = await message.guild.create_role(name=ban_str)
category = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, name="Tickets")
overwrites = {
    message.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
}
channel = await message.guild.create_text_channel(banstr, category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
user = client.fetch_user(int(user_id))
# ^ This is an API Function which you shouldn't use but in such cases you have to
await user.add_roles(role, reason="[Ban Ticket] Added user to ticket " + banstr)
```